# nodejs async control flow with loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, control-flow

What is the problem with this NodeJS code?

I have the following NodeJS snipt.

```
Profile.findOne(profileId, cb) //is sync function


function getProfiles(users, cb) {
  var results = [];
  var n = users.length;
  users.forEach(function(user, i) {
    Profile.findOne(user.profileId, function(err, prf) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, null);
      }
      console.log(prf);
      console.log(user.profileId);
      results.push(prf);
      if (i + 1 == n) {
        console.log('looping done');
        return cb(null, results);
      }
    });
  });
}

// some where 
var userslist = [{
  name: 'ab',
  profileId: 'daf242'
}, {
  name: 'cd',
  profileId: 'hg535h'
}, {
  name: 'ef',
  profileId: 'cvxv445'
}];
getProfiles(userslist, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    //do this 
  } else {
    //do that
  }
});
```

**The problem** is the results are array of **only** **profiles for  the first profileId**.
    like

```
 [
      {username:'ab',avatarUrl:'abcd.png'}
      {username:'ab',avatarUrl:'abcd.png'},
      {username:'ab',avatarUrl:'abcd.png'}
    ]
```

but I am expecting array of differnet profiles.

**what am I missing?**

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Ldd0mcrj/

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code here. Your forEach loop is running synchronously, but the `Profile.findOne` method is asynchronous. It then calls the callback passed into the initial function. You should look at using [`async` for an asynchronous for loop](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each).

However, there are many things in your question that suggest you haven't fully grasped the asynchronous nature of Node.js yet. Try reading up on the topic, such as [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: Can you elaborate  _"calls the callback passed into the initial function"_ ?

Comment: @MrWillihog could you suggest a way to fix the problem, I will read the links and lighten the topic. but now I kind of need qucik suggetion/fix.

Comment: @Rayon - the `getProfiles` function is passed a callback (`cb`). This gets called inside the `Profile.findOne` method. So in effect, the first profile to be found will pass it's result to the callback of the `getProfiles` function.

Comment: @MrWillihog – How come OP get `3` objects in array ? It had to be `1` right ?

Comment: @Rayon - yes, you're correct. It's probably a closure issue with the mix of synchronous / asynchronous code. I still think changing to use `async` will fix the problem - but this should probably have been a comment.

Comment: @Rayon - that looks like it might work. I still think replacing `forEach` with `async.each` is a better way forward though.

Comment: @MrWillihog – As far as understanding thins is concerned, old school `increment and test` is good but while dealing with more real life and complex application, __`async`__ is _must_ !

Answer (score 0):

Use *[async](http://caolan.github.io/async/)* or promises

```
var async = require('async');
...
async.map(users, Profile.findOne, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        return ...// process errors;

    userlist = results; 
})
```